# Have added maven dependency for webdrivermanager and saved pom file , but jar is not added and import io.github not resolved error is thrown

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Steps:

1. Want to use WebDriverManager and added the necessary dependency in pom.xml file and saved the file.
2. Yet , cant see the jar file added under maven dependencies
   [image]
3. Unable to import package as jar file is not added
   [image]

Please help me in resolving the issue. Stuck at this stage, unable to proceed further

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774). You can edit your question via the _Edit_ link under its tags.

Comment: Ensure that dependencies were downloaded with `mvn dependency:resolve`.

Comment: Right click the project and `Maven->Update Project...` then select the projects you want to update the click `OK`.

Comment: @Oliver , checked for dependencies and yes they are downloaded

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam yesss, it worked now. Thanks a lot!!! I can continue now!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi shrichitra dhulipala Please refer this link - https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/

Here in the Setup option copy the line onto your Pom.xml File and save it,in your editor and it imports the jar file.

Note:When we copy-pasted the entire command  WebDriverManager.chrome driver.setup() it highlights the WebDriver Manager as an Error and does not import the file.Please do not do,it that way instead type the words individually for the error to disappear and jar file to be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse won't update the maven projects if "Build Automatically" is disabled.

To update the eclipse's dependencies to reflect the dependencies in the pom.xml right click the project and `Maven->Update Project...` then select the projects you want to update the click `OK` or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, this will update you projects to reflect the dependencies in pom.xml.